# Loading child entities with parent object graph using Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6, parent-child

I am trying to model something similar to a graph representation of a object where it's children are dependencies on which the parent depends.

Example here is the table structure.

```
Initative
Id  |  Name
 1  |  Init1
 2  |  Init2
 3  |  Init3
 4  |  Init4

InitiativeChildren
Id  |InitiativeId   InitiativeChildrenId
1   |    1         |         2
2   |    1         |         3
3   |    2         |         4

Categories
Id  | InitiativeId  | Name
1   |     1         | Init1Category1
2   |     1         | Init1Category2
3   |     1         | Init1Category3
4   |     2         | Init2Category1
5   |     2         | Init2Category2
6   |     2         | Init2Category3
7   |     3         | Init3Category1
8   |     3         | Init3Category2
```

Initiative Id = 1 depends on Initiative Id = 2, 3 where InitiativeId = 2 further depends on Initiative Id = 4

I want to write a query to pull a object like this for Initiative Id = 1

```
Initiative
{
Id : 1
Children = [ Initiative { 
          Id = 2, 
          Children = [ Initiative 
          {
            Id = 4,
            Children = []
          }]
          },
          Initiative { 
          Id = 3, 
          Children = []
          }]
}
```

i.e. I want the child initiative to be Initiative Objects which will again have child initiatives and so on. 
I want the structure to be like this so that I can use depth first search to resolve the children objects before acting on that object. 
The database structure I designed is

[image]

And the Entity framework query I have written is

```
var result = context.Initiatives
                    .Include(m => m.InitiativeChildrens)
                    .Include(m => m.Categories)
                    .Where(m => m.Id == 1)
                    .ToList();
```

What I get currently is that the the ChildrenInitiative has two children as it should but the Initiative to that child initiative is again the same Initiative with Id = 1 as opposed to a Initiative Object with ChildInitiative.ChildInitiativeId

*Lets assume that this representation doesn't lead to modelling a cyclic graph for now*